# Ninject + WCF Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, unit-testing, ninject

I'm trying to use Ninject with a WCF service of mine.  I'm using Ninject 2.2.1.4 and Ninject.Extensions.Wcf 2.2.0.4.  My unit test to ensure Ninject is working properly fails with an ArgumentNullException; Parameter root: null.

Here is my code:

```
  //A couple of classes to setup ninject and its bindings
 public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<SqlEmployeeRepository>().InSingletonScope();
    }

}

 public class Global : NinjectWcfApplication
{       
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectBindings());
        return kernel;
    }
}

//Test method that fails with ArgumentNullException
  [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Be_Able_To_Get_Employee_Service_From_Ninject()
    {
        Global globalService = new Global();

        var kernel = globalService.Kernel;

        EmployeeService employeeService = kernel.Get<EmployeeService>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(employeeService);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating `Global` you have to initialize it properly by calling `Application_Start()` and `Init()` as IIS would do. After this your integration test should run.

But be aware that in reality `kernel.Get` is not triggered directly as you do in your test. The creation of the service is much more complex.

Comment: The Global is just a class, not global.asax...not sure if that's causing a problem (I'm a noob to web services).  Can you provide some code to help me rectify and make my unit test pass?  I'm not entirely clear, thanks.

Comment: Global derives from NinjectWcfApplication which is a HttpApplication w/o initialization it can't be used. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/tree/Maintenance_2.2/src

Answer (score 0):

When using `Ninject.Wcf`, your `Global` doesnt get `new`d as you've done - you tell WCF that the factory for creating Global is ~`NinjectWcfHostFactory`, which triggers the `CreateKernel()` that's not happening in your context.

The example shows the overriding of the factory (in a propery on the service declaration within the `.svc` file).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm a bit new to web services and ninject.  Can you post a little code to help me better understand how I can correct mine?

Comment: @Beavis: Not looking to go chasing around the source, but luckily @Remo Gloor did. There's also another person asking pretty much the same Q today - go look at the answers to that. Just wanted to point out that a) you're working on a false assumption b) there are samples on the ninject github that show the correct approah.